# Why is the bond angle of sulphur difluoride greater than that of hydrogen sulphide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, electrons, hybridization, valence-bond-theory

Why is the bond angle of $\ce{SF_2 (98.05^\circ) > SH_2 (92.11^\circ)}$?

Isn't this contradicting Bent's rule or otherwise electron repulsion rule ? Fluorine is more electronegative and hence it should have bonds with higher $\mathrm p$ character than those which hydrogen will form. Which means $\ce{F-S-F}$ bond angle should be smaller than $\ce{H-S-H}$ bond angle. Why is it not the case?

Source:

1. [$\ce{SH2}$ bond angle](https://cccbdb.nist.gov/expangle2x.asp?descript=aHSH&all=0)
2. [$\ce{SF2}$ bond angle](https://cccbdb.nist.gov/expangle2x.asp?descript=aFSF&all=0)

Comment: Electrostatic repulsion?

Comment: Extent of hybridization is very low in these compounds and thus Bent's rule doesn't hold.

Comment: Moreover sulphur has a positive formal charge in $\ce{SF2}$ whereas in case of $\ce{SH2}$ it has a negative formal charge.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar Any reason for not correcting “flourine” and “diflouride”?

Comment: Please note that names of chemicals or chemical elements (like 'hydrogen') should not be capitalised, unless occurring at the beginning of a sentence. Additionally, IUPAC (and most people) use the spelling 'sulfur' nowadays.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal could it possibly be back bonding by p orbital of fluorine to vacant d orbitals of sulfur?